# Get post format

Tags: php, wordpress

I needed to use the category name as a class for the H1, and also needed to exclude category 2. So I botched together the PHP code below. It works fine except the post looses it's formatting. I know that `get_post_format()` is what applies the format, but when I add it, it doesn't seem to do anything. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    $excludedcats = array(2);
    $count = 0;
    $categories = get_the_category();
    foreach($categories as $category)
    {
        $count++;
        if ( !in_array($category->cat_ID, $excludedcats) )
            {
             echo '<h1 class="category-heading ' . sprintf( __( "heading-%s" ), $category->slug ) . '" >';

             if( $count != count($categories) )
                 {
            echo " ";
             }

        }
    } 
single_post_title();
echo '</h1>';
the_content(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_post_format()` doesn't apply the format; it just returns the post type, which you can then use to apply the format. In order to have different formats for different post types, you can do something like this:

```
<?php
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
?>
```

And then you need another file, `content-[post-type-slug].php` (e.g. for image posts, the file would be called `content-image.php`) where you display the post. You could also just use a switch statement on the return value of `get_post_format()` but that can get messy.